# Closing proxy to service socket when client is lost

Tags: nginx, http, reverse-proxy

We are using nginx, right now 1.6 to reverse proxy our services to the client. We are also using Server-Sent Events, a layer on top of HTTP that keeps the socket open.

Here is a piece of required config.

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

Here is our setup

```
Client <---> nginx <---> Service
     Socket 1     Socket 2
```

When I close my browser without doing a proper disconnect, Socket 1 is closed while Socket 2 is still open. The Service is seeing that nginx is still connected and still is continuing to push messages on there.

Here is the scenario I'm seeing with wireshark.

```
Client -XXX- nginx <---> Service
     Socket 1     Socket 2
```

Is there a way to have nginx close Socket 2?

Would HTTP's `Connection: keep-alive` cause any adverse behavior?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443660/nginx-reverse-proxy-for-jersey-sse-close-wait-connections-eventually-choke-serv => in the answer it talks about nginx and proxy_read_timeout. haven't tried it myself. did you manage to solve the problem? i have the same problem with apache :-(